Can complex polyols like cellulose be acetylated with manganese acetate?
The paper by Gowda and Lokanatha Rai [1] describes the usage of manganese(III) acetate for the acetylation of primary, secondary and tertiary alcohols.
As far as I know, cellulose acetate uses acetic anhydride for the acetylation. So, does this method generalize for cellulose in any significant yield?
Reference

Gowda, S.; Lokanatha Rai, K. M. Manganese(III) Acetate as Catalyst for the Direct Acetylation of Alcohols with Acetic Acid. J. Mol. Catal. A Chem. 2004, 217 (1), 27–29. DOI: 10.1016/j.molcata.2004.03.006.

